# Preselect with angular and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to make this work; I have a search function which loads data from a database via PHP to Angular and displays everything correctly prefilled, except for one thing.

I have a select option where the user can choose a file from the server;

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <select ng-model="formData.fileChooser" class="form-control">
                <option value="Default.png">Default</option>
                <?php
                    foreach(glob('/remote/file/[^~]*.png', GLOB_ERR) as $filename) {
                    $filename = basename($filename);
                    echo "<option value=\"$filename\">".$filename."</option>\r\n";
                    }
                ?>
```

When previewing the formData I can see that fileChooser is set to the correct filename but isn't the correctly selected value, it's *always* Default.

I suspect that it has to do that the PHP is executed on that particular page (when changing state to that .php-file) after Angular already has been "initialized".

Any tips on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular looks for the current value in the model you declared, formData.fileChooser. So you need to make sure that the fileChooser property contains the correct filename.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the clarification.